# Refresh previous form table after submit button

Tags: php, sql, refresh, dropdown

How do I refresh the table when I click EDIT NOW Button? or this is easier, how do I make refresh button to refresh the table? I have no knowledge on JSP to auto refresh. However, I manage to make an onchange event so when I choose menu, it will refresh upon changing. When I edit a data and submit, it does not refresh. How do I re-execute the echo of table? Thanks!

[image]

```
    <?php



    $selected='';

    function get_options($select)
    {
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
        or die ('Cannot connect to db');

        $result = $conn->query("select * from students");

        $options='';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $LRN = $row['LRN'];
             $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
            $First = $row['First_Name'];
            if($LRN == $_GET['Students'])
            {
                $options.='<option value="'.$LRN.'" selected>'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';

            }
            else
            {
                $options.='<option value="'.$LRN.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
        if (isset($_GET['Students'])) {
            $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
        or die ('Cannot connect to db');

        $result = $conn->query("select * from students");
        $lrn = $_GET['Students'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Level, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, FINAL FROM english WHERE LRN = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $lrn);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($last, $first, $level, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $final);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo "<table><tr><th>LRN</th><th>Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th><th>Q4</th><th>Final</th></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>$lrn</td><td>$last, $first</td><td>$level</td><td>$q1</td><td>$q2</td><td>$q3</td><td>$q4</td><td>$final</td></tr></table>";
    }




    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<form method=GET>";
    echo "<select name=Students onchange=this.form.submit();>";

        echo get_options();



    echo "</select>";
    echo "</form>";

    echo "<form method=POST>";
    ///////////EDIT DATA
    echo "Edit Data: ";
    echo "<select name = 'Edit'>";

    echo '<option value=Q1>Q1</option>';
    echo '<option value=Q2>Q2</option>';
    echo '<option value=Q3>Q3</option>';
    echo '<option value=Q4>Q4</option>';
    echo '<option value=FINAL>FINAL</option>';
    echo '<input type="number" max="100" name="editdata" required>';
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2' value='Edit Now'>";


    if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {
        $conn2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
        or die ('Cannot connect to db');
        $upd = $_POST['Edit'];
        $txt = $_POST['editdata'];
        $now = "UPDATE english SET $upd='$txt' WHERE LRN='$lrn'";
        $res = $conn2->query($now);
        if (!$conn2->error) {
            echo "Errormessage: $conn->error";
    }
        echo $now;



    }



    echo "</form>";





    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Try using ajax on your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 2 pages view.php and edit.php.  View would display the data with link to edit.  When you click edit it would open edit.php to load the form to edit data and save it to db.  Then issue the command

```
header("Location: view.php");
```

to reload the view.php and display the new data

I have uploaded the scripts I use as a basis for databases so you can see if this is what you want - feel free to amend any data it is just a test database.  If you want more code just ask

```
<a href="http://www.cambodia.me.uk/php/view.php">www.cambodia.me.uk/php/view.php</a>
```

Edited to include scripts as requested - sorry it is old code and mysql not mysqli

Connect script

```
<?php
/*
CONNECT-DB.PHP
Allows PHP to connect to your database
*/
// Database Variables (edit with your own server information)
$server = 'server';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = 'database';
// Connect to Database
$connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass)
or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db($db)
or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());
?>
```

View script

```
<?php    
include('remote-connect.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>date</th> <th>Home Team</th> <th></th><th></th><th>Away Team</th> <th></th>  </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['hometeam'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['fthg'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['ftag'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['awayteam'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
//echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function renderForm($id, $hometeam, $awayteam, $error)
{
if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<div>
<p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="hometeam" value="<?php echo $hometeam; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Last Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="awayteam" value="<?php echo $awayteam; ?>"/><br/>
<p>* Required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
include('remote-connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
$id = $_POST['id'];
$hometeam = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['hometeam']));
$awayteam = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['awayteam']));
if ($hometeam == '' || $awayteam == '')
{
$error = 'ERROR: Please complete all mandatory fields!';
renderForm($id, $hometeam, $awayteam, $error);
}
else
{
mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET hometeam='$hometeam', awayteam='$awayteam' WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());
// Go back to view page and redisplay the edited data
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
else
{
echo 'Error!';
}
}
else
{
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id=$id")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row)
{
$hometeam = $row['hometeam'];
$awayteam = $row['awayteam'];
renderForm($id, $hometeam, $awayteam, '');
}
else
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else
{
echo 'Error!';
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hakkikonu and I have both given you the answer.  Simply refresh the data with a new sql query and redisplay the form.  In my solution I use 2 scripts, one displays the data with an edit option the second displays a form so you can edit the data then issues the 

header("Location: view.php"); 

command and re-displays all the new data with option to edit - job done

Comment: Looking at your code when you first run the script it displays the current data with a form to edit.  All you need to do is when the edit and update is done is include the line 

    header("Location: YourFileName.php");

and it will re-execute retrieving and displaying the new data again

Comment: sorry - comment removed - I posted on wrong question

Comment: @jaredpianist - do you want to accept either answer as correct or make any further comments

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy. If you fetch your table's values after edit or delete operation, sql will bring fresh data.